# How to remove list of Homebrew commands on every terminal start-up?

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, homebrew

This is more of an annoyance than something that actually affects my code, but I figured I'd ask about it in case someone else has found a solution.

Every time I start up my terminal, this long list of Homebrew commands populates, and it is just incredibly irritating.

**Any advice on how to stop this from populating every time i startup my terminal?** I'm on a Mac if that matters.

Any help or insight would be much appreciated. Thanks!

[image: List of Homebrew commands]

Answer (score 2):

So I did a bit of digging, and I found that the issue stemmed from my .zprofile file. With the new M1 macs, we are required to add a line of code to a file titled .zprofile when installing Homebrew by running the command below.

`echo 'eval $(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)' >> /Users/$USER/.zprofile`

`eval $(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)`

After looking in my .zprofile file, I noticed several lines of the following code: `eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew)"`, which I believe is an older version that does not work with the new M1 macs. I must have typed that command in several times when it wasn't working because (again, after digging) I learned that the `echo` command adds a new line to the .zprofile file every time it's run. (Src: comments from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69422964/brew-command-line-mac-is-not-working-without-following-steps).

To solve the problem, I went into my .zprofile file in TextEdit and removed all of those extra lines of text. Now, when my terminal loads, it is clean!

Answer (score 1):

The shell in your case (which you can determine by typing `echo $SHELL`) has startup files that are the most likely source of this. You may need some help editing that file for syntax errors as well.

Worst case, you can [search here for questions relating to dotfiles](https://apple.stackexchange.com/search?q=Dotfiles) and your shell if that helps narrow down what this means to you for next steps.

Very rarely, it can be [startup commands for the application that you run to get to your shell](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/258900/5472).

Comment: I think I figured it out. In my .zprofile file, I had 5 lines of `eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"` and 2 lines of `eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew)"`. I installed homebrew awhile ago, but it must not have worked at first, so I kept entering the same command, not knowing that it was writing to my .zprofile file. A comment in this inquiry helped me narrow it down. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69422964/brew-command-line-mac-is-not-working-without-following-steps

Comment: Nice. Please post an answer as your process and words will help far more people that have the same question as you. This happens to a ton of people getting started with shell customization - the syntax can be opaque, indeed.